# How to make a collapse bootstrap menu (not navbar) where the collapse is disabled on desktop view and enabled on mobile view?

Tags: html, css

How would I go about making a category menu that will collapse on mobile view, but stays open on the desktop view?

Comment: Media queries! https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/

Comment: When the size is [mobile-size], set the element to display:none. When the screen size is [other sizes], set the element to display: block!

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript code

```
function checkPosition() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        $('.example').hide()
    } else {
        $('.example').show()

    }
}
```

or you can use media query in css:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp